# Where should i locate the setpoint change in the python code; after or before solving the MPC(m.solve(disp=True))?

Tags: gekko

I am trying to use GEKKO to control the concentration and temperature of a CSTR while manipulating the cooling temperature and the inlet flow. I am confused about the position of the setpoint change in the python code. In one example on the APMonitor website, the setpoint of the controlled variables were put before the mpc solve option; that was used when m.options.CV_TYPE was equal to 2. One another case was when m.options.CV_TYPE was equal to 1 and the setpoint change was put after the mpc solving option.

Thank you.

Comment: Please show some code to make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: I will add two codes as an "answer to my question" to illustrate the differences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, the setpoint sequence should be located before the solver execution command (m.solve()) regardless of the CV_TYPE. 
However, if your code wrapped by 'For' loop for the realtime execution, the location of setpoint sequence can be either before and after the 'm.solve()' command depending on how you structure the 'For' loop.

I think all the CSTR example code in the below website have 'For' loop. So, that might be a reason for the variation of location.

http://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/NonlinearControl